# Import getting started Content has encountered a error

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to create a project in STS 3.7.1. When I tried creating a spring starter project, it is giving me an error something like this...

IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://start.spring.io/starter.zip?name=hello-boot&groupId=org.test&artifactId=hello-boot&version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT&description=hello+boot&packageName=org.test.demo&type=maven-project&packaging=jar&javaVersion=1.8&language=java&bootVersion=1.2.7.RELEASE&dependencies=web

I tried creating the project with different name, re-installing. No success. Can anybody suggest what is the problem? I am using 1.8 JDK for this version.enter image description here

Please find attached screenshot for your reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csW4g.jpg)
Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't know yet what exactly is going on here, but other people reported the same thing, so I created a bug tracker item for this: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4255 - please follow and comment on the bug.